# Empty model in z3

Tags: python, z3

**z3py snippet:**

```
x = Int('x')

s = Solver()
s.add(x <= x)
print s.check()
print s.model()
print s.model().sexpr()
```

http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/mfPU

**Output:**

```
sat
[]
```

Any value of `x` would do but `z3` returns empty model. 
Does a missing free variable `x` in the model indicates that any integer value is a valid model?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, in Z3, if a constant (such as `x`) does not appear in the model, then it is a "don't care". That is, any value of `x` will satisfy the formula. When evaluating the value of a constant, we can enable "model completion". That is, Z3 will use an arbitrary interpretation for "don't care" symbols. Here is an example http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/bvVO

```
x = Int('x')
s = Solver()
s.add(x <= x)
print s.check()
m = s.model()
print m.evaluate(x)
print m.evaluate(x, model_completion=True)
print m
```