# Getting all solutions of a boolean expression in Z3Py never ends

Tags: z3, z3py

Probably a basic question related to Z3: i am trying to get all solutions of a boolean expression, e.g. for `a OR b`, i want to get `{(true, true),(false,true),(true,false)}`

Based on other responses found, e.g. [Z3: finding all satisfying models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13395391/z3-finding-all-satisfying-models), i have the following code:

```
a = Bool('a')
b = Bool('b')

f1=Or(a,b)
s=Solver()
s.add(f1)

while s.check() == sat:
  print s
  s.add(Not(And(a == s.model()[a], b == s.model()[b])))
```

The issue is that it enters an infinite loop as at the second iteration: the constraint `a == s.model()[a]` is evaluated to false b/c `s.model()[a]` does not exist anymore.

Can someone tell what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advice you to try writing your loop like this instead:

```py
from z3 import *

a = Bool('a')
b = Bool('b')

f1 = Or(a,b)
s = Solver()
s.add(f1)

while s.check() == sat:

    m = s.model()

    v_a = m.eval(a, model_completion=True)
    v_b = m.eval(b, model_completion=True)

    print("Model:")
    print("a := " + str(v_a))
    print("b := " + str(v_b))

    bc = Or(a != v_a, b != v_b)
    s.add(bc)
```

The output is:

```
Model:
a := True
b := False
Model:
a := False
b := True
Model:
a := True
b := True
```

The argument `model_completion=True` is necessary because otherwise `m.eval(x)` behaves like the identity relation for any `x` Boolean variable with a *don't care* value in the current model `m` and it returns `x` as a result instead of `True/False`. ([See related Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12908067/empty-model-in-z3))

---

**NOTE:** since `z3` kindly marks *don't care* Boolean variables, an alternative option would be to write your own model generator that auto-completes any partial model. This would reduce the number of calls to `s.check()`. The performance impact of this implementation is hard to gauge, but it might be slightly faster.

Comment: Thanks Patrick for your quick reply - The output i get from your script is ```[a = True, b = False]
[b = True]``` - The infinite loop is indeed fixed, but how can i deduce the set of solutions?

Comment: Instead of printing in the loop, simply put the values a and b as a pair in an accumulated list and return it at the end.

Comment: forgive my ignorance, but how does it solve the issue? The loop will still iterate only twice   while i am expecting it to iterate three times. Or should i understand that when only ```[b = True]``` is returned, this means that ```a``` can take any value?

Comment: @f1f2 the issue is that the model value of `a` is equal to `a` at the second iteration, this is likely because the value of `a` is a `don't care` in the second model. I've to think a couple minutes how to fix the script :)

Comment: Patrick's solution works great. But to add to my comment, when you do an `eval`, you explicitly get a value, so you avoid the "completion" problem.

Comment: @alias without `model_completion=True`, not necessarily.. `m.eval(a)` yields `a` at the second iteration

Comment: On second thought, I guess the fact that `eval` takes `model_completion` as a parameter is good indication that they have anticipated this problem. So yeah, always pass `model_completion=True` to your calls to `eval`. Good advice.

Comment: thank you both, your answers exceeded my expectations :)

Comment: @Patrick, i think the sentence "...z3 returns the identity for any don't care Boolean variables." in the accepted answer should have a negation: by default z3 does not return the identity of _don't_ _care_ variables.

Comment: @f1f2 what I meant to say is that `m.eval(a)` for `a` being a *don't care* returns `a`, that is, `eval` behaves like the identity relation for *don't care* Boolean variables.